# Breakpoints in NUnit and stopping Debugging - How to kill a Test?

Tags: nunit

My apologies, it is an odd use case but please bear with me.

I have a simple TestFixture (as shown below) that outside of calling a PrimeService to check whether or not a number is prime, logs to a file whenever a routine is hit (ie. OneTimeSetup, Setup, OneTimeTearDown etc.)

Can someone please explain to me why If I run the following scenario, the TestFixture runs in it's entirety?

1. I place a breakpoint in my Test right before my Assert.
2. I start a "Debug Tests" process in VS (2019)
3. When the test pauses (and it will on the first test naturally), I press the "Stop Debugging" button (shift F5)

If I go and open my log file, I will see that all 3 tests ran, as did the TearDowns and final Teardown.

My apologies, I just want to understand what is going on under the hood, and whether or not there is a way to kill a paused Test run.

Thanks.

```
 [TestFixture]
    public class PrimeService_IsPrimeShould
    {

        private NerdAnalysis.PrimeService _primeService;
        private System.IO.StreamWriter file;
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void OneTimeSetup()
        {
            file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Fozzy Bear\source\repos\NunitTutorial\MyFile.txt");
            file.WriteLine("One time SetUp");

        }

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            _primeService = new NerdAnalysis.PrimeService();
            file.WriteLine("Setup");
        }
        [TestCase(-1)]
        [TestCase(0)]
        [TestCase(1)]
        public void IsPrime_lessthan2_pass(int value)
        {
            file.WriteLine("Running test for value " + value);
            var result = _primeService.IsPrime(value);
            Assert.IsFalse(result, "${ value} should not be prime");
            var breakLine = "break";
            Assert.Pass();

        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void FinalTearDown() {
            file.WriteLine("Final Teardown");
            file.Close();
            file.Dispose();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        { 
            file.WriteLine("Tear down");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/406kfbs1.aspx

> Stop Debugging terminates the process you are debugging if the program
> was launched from Visual Studio. If you attached to the process,
> instead of launching it from Visual Studio, the process continues
> running. If you want to terminate attached processes, you can
> terminate a single process from the Processes window or terminate all
> attached process with the Terminate All command.